# Replace newlines in some lines with spaces using sed or awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, tr

I have a text log file with some events and I want to modify it to improve readability and printing format.

I have:

```
$cat myfile 
foo bar foo bar

1.
1. foo bar
1:00

10.
3. foo bar
3:02

11.
4. foo
5:01

foobar foo

11.
foobar foo
3:48

2.
foobar foo
4:18
```

What I want is:

```
$cat myfile
foo bar foo bar

1. 1. foo bar 1:00
10. 3. foo bar 3:02
11 4. foo 5:01

foobar foo

11. foobar foo 3:48
2. foobar foo 4:18
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/^[0-9]+\./{ORS=" "} !NF{ORS="\n"};1; END{ORS="";print RS}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
foo bar foo bar

1. 1. foo bar 1:00
10. 3. foo bar 3:02
11. 4. foo 5:01
foobar foo

11. foobar foo 3:48
2. foobar foo 4:18
```

***EDIT:*** Adding a non-one liner form of solution with explanation too here.

```
awk '
/^[0-9]+\./{  ##Checking condition here if any line starts from a digit(all together) and with a dot if yes then do following.
  ORS=" "     ##Setting value of ORS(output record separator) as space here.
}
!NF{          ##Checking if value of awk out of the box variable named NF value is NULL here, if yes then do following.
  ORS="\n"    ##Setting the value of ORS(output record separator) as new line here.
};
1;            ##By mentioning 1 here I am making condition TRUE here and not mentioning any action so by default print of current line will happen.
END{
  ORS="";     ##Setting value of ORS(output field separator) as NULL here.
  print RS    ##Printing value of RS which is new line by default.
}
' Input_file  ##Mentioning Input_file here.
```

Answer (score 4):

by setting the record to paragraph mode

```
awk -v RS=  '{$1=$1}1'
```

you'll get

```
foo bar foo bar
1. 1. foo bar 1:00
10. 3. foo bar 3:02
11. 4. foo 5:01
foobar foo
11. foobar foo 3:48
2. foobar foo 4:18
```

to add the extra empty lines, requires some additions

```
awk -v RS=  '{$1=$1; t=!/[0-9]\./; 
              if(NR>1 && t) print ""; 
              print; 
              if(t) print ""}'
```

to get

```
foo bar foo bar

1. 1. foo bar 1:00
10. 3. foo bar 3:02
11. 4. foo 5:01

foobar foo

11. foobar foo 3:48
2. foobar foo 4:18
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -l -000 -pe 's/^|$/\n/g if 2 != s/\n/ /g' -- file
```

- `-000` turns on the "paragraph mode" which reads the input in blocks delimited by empty lines
- `-l` removes the input separator from input and adds it to output
- `s/\n/ /g` replaces all newlines (in a block) by spaces and returns the number of substitutions
- `s/^|$/\n/g` adds a newline to the beginning and end of a block

Answer (score 0):

You could try this awk version:

```
awk '/\.$/{printf "%s ", $0; next} {print} your-file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed

```
sed ':A;$bB;N;/\n$/!bA;:B;s/\n//g;s/\(^[^0-9]*$\)/\n&\n/;1,2s/^\n//' myfile

sed '
:A
$bB                     # jump to B if last line
N                       # add a new line in the pattern space
/\n$/!bA                # if this new line is empty, not return to A
:B
s/\n//g                 # remove all \n to get only one line
s/\(^[^0-9]*$\)/\n&\n/  # if the line not contain number add \n before and after
1,2s/^\n//              # remove the \n before the first line
' myfile
```